# JButton responds in JFrame, but not in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm new to java and I'm trying to figure out how action listeners and buttons work. I've found that I can get a working JButton if I put it directly into my JFrame object. But if I put it in a JPanel *within* that JFrame, it won't respond. Why is that?

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    private static Frame f = new Frame();
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

**Frame.java**

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    private final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = 480;
    private Panel p = new Panel();

    Frame() {
        super("Java Program");   
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        p.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

**Panel.java**

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {
    JButton b = new JButton("Button");

    Panel() {
        b.setBounds(0,  0, 200, 100);
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                b.setText("Pressed");
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        b.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never add the panel `p` to the frame... also don't explicitly call `paintComponent` on elements like that. Swing will do that automatically.

Comment: And don't override paint() of the frame or paintComponent() of the panel.. There is no reason to do that. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for working examples to get you started. The examples will show a better way to structure your code.

Comment: @Obicere Well spotted. `this.setLayout(null);` This part in the frame code will likely also cause problems once components **are** added.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). BTW - where are you getting information on how to code Java? I ask because you should change it. There are more code lines in the above snippets that are (potentially) causing problems than there are rigorous and well written lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a Swing expert so I can't really explain why it does not work. It seems like an unresponsive button is painted on top of you button. I tweaked it a little and here are a few modifications to get it to work:

- Add the panel to the Frame: `add(p);`
- Remove the `this.setLayout(null);` line, it seems to mess up the frame
- To set the size of the Frame, use setPreferredSize: `this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));`
- You also need to call `pack()` at then end of your Frame constructor.
- And you need to remove `b.paint(g)` from your `Panel.paintComponent()`, this seems to be what paints the "unresponsive" button, (see image at the end of the answer).
- Optionally, you can remove the paint() from the Frame, it does nothing more than the JFrame's one

Here is a modified working version:

```
class Frame extends JFrame {
    private final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = 480;
    private Panel p = new Panel();

    Frame() {
        super("Java Program");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

        // add the panel to the frame
        add(p);

        pack();
    }

}

class Panel extends JPanel {
    JButton b = new JButton("Button");

    Panel() {
        b.setBounds(0,  0, 200, 100);
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                b.setText("Pressed");
            }
        });
    }


    // You can also get rid of this method, 
    // I just leave it here to show that I removed the b.paint(g) line
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Here is what the same code shows if you leave `b.paint(g)` in `Panel.paintComponent()`, as you can see there are 2 buttons, the one in the corner does not work.

[image]